# Send message from content script to pop-up even when pop-up is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a chrome extension which should extract the video title from a YouTube page and show the title in the extension pop-up. This works when the popup is open and I refresh the page, but if the pop-up is closed I get this error while sending the message,

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Is there a way that I can consistently send messages from content script to the pop-up even if the pop-up is closed?

***content.js***

```
window.onload = () => {
  const videoTitle = document.querySelector(
    "#title h1 yt-formatted-string"
  )?.textContent;
  if (videoTitle) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, {
      type: "VIDEO_NAME",
      value: videoTitle,
    });
  }
};
```

***popup.js***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("Request: ", request, "Sender: ", sender);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the action popup is closed it doesn't run and can't receive messages.

Simply get the current title each time the popup is shown:

// popup.js

```js
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  const [{ result }] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript(({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: () => document.querySelector('#title h1 yt-formatted-string')?.textContent,
  }));
  document.body.textContent = result;
})();
```

P.S. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.